# Loading images in HTML

Tags: html, css

We are doing a html project. In this project, we are using many images. 
Please verify the below scenarios,

Scenario 1:

- Uploading single image (a.jpg)
- In main page we are setting the width and loading the image (a.jpg) in 950x450 sizes.
- In description page we are setting the width and loading the image (a.jpg) in 400x200 sizes.
- In footer we are setting the width and loading the image (a.jpg) in 50x50 sizes.

Scenario 2:

- Uploading copy of single images with different size (a_size1.jpg,
  a_size2.jpg)
- In main page we are loading the a_size1.jpg.
- In description page we are loading the a_size2.jpg.

Which scenario we need to follow? and why?

Scenario 1: Is there any performance issue?
Scenario 2: Fast, but more memory space.

Comment: fast answer: number 2. woudln't the footer image result shrunk to a square, not respecting original proportions?

Comment: But doing the second method, you have to spend a lot time to take copies with different sizes of each image. Right?

Comment: if you already know the target sizes, you could automatize the copy&resizing task server side (don't know what technology you're using), and upload a single time the image at the biggest size

Comment: I think that the best is in the middle, call it scenario 1,5.
Load full image and then resize it client side with html/css is a waste of memory and bandwith, have a copy for all size it's a waste of disk space on the server.
In my opinion you need only one copy on server and then, according to client's request, resize the image and send it to the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Scenario 1: Is there any performance issue?**

Yes. Because in description and footer pages, image with full size is loaded. Then bandwidth is wasted and loading will be slower

**Scenario 2: Fast, but more memory space.**

Yes, it's faster while loading image. But the cost is not memory space, it's hard disk space. You load images into memory only when the image is requested. And in fact loading images with smaller size will cost less runtime memory. By the way, you only need to upload one single image, then, in server side, you can use some image processing library(like Thumbnailator in java) to automatically  generate images with smaller size.

Comment: He said in description **page**